# When ever i filtered my list using search it gave me filtered value. when my search bar is empty it doesn't gave me my original list back in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, search, filter, ionic4

When ever i filtered my list using search it gave me filtered value. when my search bar is empty it doesn't gave me my original list back in ionic.

page.html

```
<ion-searchbar 
  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"  
  [(ngModel)]="searchList"
  (input)="setFilteredTitle()" 
  class="search">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Page.ts

```
filterItems(searchTerm){
  return this.result.filter(item => {
    return item.category_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
}

filterList(searchList){
  return this.result2.filter(items => {
    return items.store_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchList.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
}

setFilteredTitle(){
  this.showlist = true
  this.result = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm)
  this.result2 = this.filterList(this.searchList)
}
```

In ionic, I want to search two different lists from a single search bar I used these functions. It filtered my data. But whenever I remove value from the search bar it doesn't give me back my original List and before refresh doesn't filter again. what's the issue please help thanx in advance.

Comment: are you sure you have multiple `ngModel` on a single input field?

Comment: Ya I know it might be wrong but it works for me.. is that you have any other solution please suggest thanx

Comment: What is happening is the you are binding the search results into same array that contains the list, so when you search for example it matches 2 found and they are displayed, now the main data list is replaced with these 2 results and when the search box characters is cleared, then 0 result will be found and thus the main array of data will be cleared, so either you change your search way or add another array to display the results found and put ngIf's to hide main array if searchBox is making search, but preffare to do search using search pipe.

Answer (score 0):

With your current logic you can only get value if it matches in the array and when you clear the value it doesn't match anything and you get an empty `Array`. So you need to change your logic to return the same array if you get nothing in the `searchTerm`. Your code should look something like this. I haven't played with `ion-searchbar` so idk about the list variable here but you get the idea what I'm talking about.

```
filterItems(searchTerm){
  if(!searchTerm) return this.result;
  return this.result.filter(item => {
    return item.category_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
}

filterList(searchList){
  if(!searchList) return this.result2;
  return this.result2.filter(items => {
    return items.store_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchList.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
}
```

Comment: oK i will check

Comment: ok. so we are updating the same variable from which we are taking out the values. So we filter `result` and `result2` and update them to be the new value. To filter value from you need to have a global variable which you're not mutating.